# UnsupportedOperationException - Why can't you call toInstant() on a java.sql.Date?

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

The `java.util.Date` class has a method called `toInstant()` that converts the `Date` instance to a `java.time.Instant`.

The `java.sql.Date` class extends the `java.util.Date` class, but when I attempt to call `toInstant()` on a `java.sql.Date`, I receive an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Why is `toInstant()` an unsupported operation on `java.sql.Date`?

And what is the "correct" way to convert a `java.sql.Date` to a `java.time.Instant`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

According to the [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toInstant--)

Since `sql.Date` does not have a time component, there is no possibility to convert it to `time.Instant`

> This method always throws an UnsupportedOperationException and should
> not be used because SQL Date values do not have a time component.

Comment: Now, the question is _why_ it was designed this way. One could imagine it defaults with time info set to 0. Can't find anything in the mailing list.

Comment: @Tunaki The logic makes me think it is because the parent class `util.Date` has a public `toInstant` method that should not be used by the child class. So instead of making it `final` (to keep the Inheritance logic), they preferred the option of overriding it and making it unusable.

Comment: @Tunaki probably because, as you point out, any conversion into an Instant would require setting some data arbitrarily (time, time zone).

Comment: But `Instant` using the same logic that `java.util.Date` uses would produce correct and logical results, while avoiding violating the polymorphism contract. Oracle has made a very headscratching choice, there.

Answer (score 62):

The correct mapping between `java.sql.Date` and `java.time` is `LocalDate`:

```
LocalDate date = sqlDate.toLocalDate();
```

*If you really must*, you can then derive an `Instant`, although the extra information (time) will be arbitrary. For example:

```
Instant i = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneOffset.UTC).toInstant();
```

Comment: Wish I could accept two answers... This answers the second part of my question perfectly, but the main question was why you can't call `toInstant()` on a `java.sql.Date`, so I had to accept [@YassinHajaj](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5050667/yassin-hajaj)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36435570/2561365). This answer needs more upvotes.

Comment: Since `date` is a LocalDate (local timezone), shouldn't the conversion to Instant (which is UTC) specify the local timezone?: `Instant i = date.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()`

Comment: LocalDate date = sqlDate.toLocalDate(); is not performable

Comment: @YannickMussche not sure what you mean: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Date.html#toLocalDate()

Comment: try it in your IDE, it doesn't work.

Comment: @YannickMussche https://ideone.com/4G8O06

Answer (score 38):

[java.sql.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html) supports only Date components (date, month, year). It does NOT support time components (hour, minute, second, millisecond). [toInstant](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toInstant) requires both Date and Time components, so toInstant on java.sql.Date instance throws UnsupportedOperationException exception.

**toInstant Java doc**

> This method always throws an
> UnsupportedOperationException and should not be used because SQL Date
> values do not have a time component.

java.util.Date OR java.sql.Timestamp has both Date/Time components, so toInstant() works!

You can do like this:

```
// Time is 00:00:00.000

new java.util.Date(sqlDate.getTime()).toInstant()
```

**Updated:**

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli(sqlDate.getTime());

// and
new java.util.Date(sqlDate.getTime()).toInstant();
```

will return the same result because the toInstant() method calls Instant.ofEpochMilli(getTime()) internally.

```
public Instant toInstant() {
    return Instant.ofEpochMilli(getTime());
}
```

Comment: Which is more "correct"? `Instant.ofEpochMilli(sqlDate.getTime());` or `new java.util.Date(sqlDate.getTime()).toInstant();`

Comment: You can’t convert a java.sql.Date into an Instant without supplying a timezone. Calling getTime() at an java.sql.Date is meaningless. As pointed out in other comments, java.sql.Date is only a LocalDate and doesn’t represent an instant in time.

Comment: I didn't call toInstant on java sql date. I did call toInstant on java util date and it is ok for the case.

Answer (score 20):

The answers given so far until now concentrate on the detail that `java.sql.Date` has no time information. That is correct but not the real or sufficient reason why this type cannot offer a direct conversion to `Instant`. Unfortunatly the [documentation of Java-8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toInstant--) does make the same mistake to let users think the problem is just because of missing time information.

Conceptually, the type `java.sql.Date` represents a local type. It models a calendar date which can be different in any region of our globe. But an `Instant` is the same on our globe around. **So users need a timezone or a timezone offset to do the conversion.**

Tragically, the type `java.sql.Date` inherits from `java.util.Date` which is a global type (instant-like). However, this inheritance really denotes implementation inheritance, and not type inheritance. One more reason to consider the design of these old JDBC-classes to be broken. Therefore it is indeed possible to use the hack to wrap the `java.sql.Date` via its method `getTime()` inside an instance of `java.util.Date` which finally allows direct conversion to an instant. But: This conversion implicitly uses the default timezone of the system.

So how to correctly convert in a pedantic way? Let's consider the [documentation of Java-8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toLocalDate--) again which here points into the right direction:

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = ...;
LocalDate calendarDate = sqlDate.toLocalDate();
ZonedDateTime zdt = calendarDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Europe/Paris"));
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant();
```

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have time in your Date - convert it to millis:

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime())
   .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
   .toLocalDate();
```

Answer (score 3):

The implementation of java.sql.Date (imho) is really not perfect.

In order to convert java.util.Date to LocalDate the web is full of code blocks like this:

```
dateToConvert.toInstant()
  .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
  .toLocalDate();
```

- above code works perfect for java.util.Date because of the way it implements toInstant(). (As expected " return Instant.ofEpochMilli(getTime())")
- As java.sql.Date is a subclass of java.util.Date code operating on the Date object might now know it operates on a java.sql.Date. (Hey - that's one aspect of object orientation, right??). So if it gets java.util.Date code works well, if it gets java.sql.Date it fails.
- Code could now explicitly check for the Date type, and then (if it operates on java.sql.Date) it could do a downcast to java.sql.Date and use the toLocalDate() method. Needless to say, that this is ugly.

As developer I'd like to have one method working properly - toLocalDate (internally using deprectated methods) only exists for java.sql.Date so cannot be used on java.util.Date, and toInstant fails on java.sql.Date.

I changed my "Date to LocalDate" conversion code to this:

```
public static LocalDate asLocalDate(java.util.Date date) {
    return date == null ? null : LocalDate.ofInstant(Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime()), ZoneId.systemDefault());
}
```

This works independent of the date type passed in. Basically it means "dont call java.util.Date.toInstant() as you might get a java.sql.Date, which then breaks your code.

I really don't understand why they implement such traps on purpose within the JDK.

Comment: It's a very head-scratching choice on the part of the original designers, indeed. There was no reason to break the polymorphic contract.