# Truncating java.util.Date to LocalDate *without* toInstant() because java.sql.Date gives UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: java, date, datetime, java-time, date-conversion

If I use `java.util.Date`'s `toInstant()` on a variable which happens to be a `java.sql.Date`, I get an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

```
try {
    java.util.Date input = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    LocalDate date = input.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
} catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
    // grrr!
}
```

The `java.util.Date` that I'm concerned with comes from a DATE field in a mysql DB via a legacy API, and is actually a `java.sql.Date`.

Now the following related questions are all very interesting:

[UnsupportedOperationException - Why can't you call toInstant() on a java.sql.Date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36435492/unsupportedoperationexception-why-cant-you-call-toinstant-on-a-java-sql-dat)

[Convert java.util.Date to java.time.LocalDate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21242110/convert-java-util-date-to-java-time-localdate)

[LocalDate to java.util.Date and vice versa simplest conversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066904/localdate-to-java-util-date-and-vice-versa-simplest-conversion)

but they don't provide any elegant way of truncating a `java.util.Date` to get rid of the time component and get a Java 8 `LocalDate`.

I admit there is an issue that the same instant in time in one timezone might be a different date from the same instant in another timezone.

I suspect the solution will involve java.util.Calendar but rather than craft my own solution I'd rather establish what others have done first.

I'd prefer to find something shorter than this:

> from [Resetting the time part of a timestamp in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227007/resetting-the-time-part-of-a-timestamp-in-java) :
>
> ```
> Date date = new Date();                      // timestamp now
> Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();       // get calendar instance
> cal.setTime(date);                           // set cal to date
> cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);            // set hour to midnight
> cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);                 // set minute in hour
> cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);                 // set second in minute
> cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);            // set millis in second
> Date zeroedDate = cal.getTime();             // actually computes the new Date
> ```

Comment: Why not use the [toLocalDate method of java.sql.Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toLocalDate--)?

Comment: Isn't `LocalDate date = ((java.sql.Date) input).toLocalDate();` enough?

Comment: @VGR Exactly. On using `toInstant()` the JavaDoc says: *This method always throws an UnsupportedOperationException and should not be used because SQL Date values do not have a time component.*

Comment: @Hugo it might also *not* be a `java.sql.Date`

Comment: I believe that your problem is that the inheritance relationship is deceiving: it suggests you should be able to handle both `Date` types uniformly and polymorphically, which was not intended.

Comment: yes, certainly not very SOLID

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Often the simplest solutions are the hardest to find:

```
public LocalDate convertDateObject(java.util.Date suspectDate) {

    try {
        // Don't do this if there is the smallest chance 
        // it could be a java.sql.Date!
        return suspectDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

    } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
        // BOOM!!
    }

    // do this first:
    java.util.Date safeDate = new Date(suspectDate.getTime());

    return safeDate.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

}
```

Answer (score 8):

If the `input` variable is known to be a `java.sql.Date`, then you can simply cast it and call the `toLocalDate()` method:

```
LocalDate date = ((java.sql.Date) input).toLocalDate();
```

Unfortunately, you can't call `toInstant()` on a `java.sql.Date`, because [according to javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#toInstant--), it always throws an `UnsupportedOperationException`.

If you don't know the type (it can be either a `java.util.Date` or a `java.sql.Date`), you can use the value returned by `getTime()` method to build an `Instant`, then convert it to a timezone (below I'm using the JVM's default) and finally get the local date from it:

```
LocalDate date = Instant
    // get the millis value to build the Instant
    .ofEpochMilli(input.getTime())
    // convert to JVM default timezone
    .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    // convert to LocalDate
    .toLocalDate();
```

The `toLocalDate()` method gets the date part (day/month/year), ignoring the rest, so there's no need to truncate it: it doesn't matter if the time is midnight, 10 AM, or any other time of the day, `toLocalDate()` will ignore it and get just the date part.

If you really want to set the time to midnight, though, you can use the [`with` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster-) and pass a [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) to it:

```
LocalDate date = Instant
    // get the millis value to build the Instant
    .ofEpochMilli(input.getTime())
    // convert to JVM default timezone
    .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
    // set time to midnight
    .with(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT)
    // convert to LocalDate
    .toLocalDate();
```

But as I said, the `toLocalDate()` method will just ignore the time part, so setting the time is not needed in this case (the `LocalDate` will be the same).

---

You could also check the date's type and choose the proper action accordingly, like this:

```
if (input instanceof java.sql.Date) {
    date = ((java.sql.Date) input).toLocalDate();
} else {
    date = input.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
}
```

---

Instead of using the JVM default timezone (`ZoneId.systemDefault()`), you can use any other timezone, according to your needs, by calling `ZoneId.of("zoneName")`, where the zone name is any of the valid [IANA timezones names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) (always in the format `Region/City`, like `America/New_York` or `Europe/London`).
Avoid using the 3-letter abbreviations (like `CET` or `PST`) because they are [ambiguous and not standard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18407231/7605325).

You can get a list of available timezones (and choose the one that fits best your system) by calling `ZoneId.getAvailableZoneIds()`. You can also keep using the JVM default timezone if you want, but remind that it [can be changed without notice, even at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45797132/7605325), so it's better to always make it explicit which one you're using.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class )
```

## java.time

Your troubles started when using the legacy date-time classes such as `java.sql.Date`, `java.util.Date`, and `Calendar`. Avoid these classes entirely. They are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

You said the value began as a stored value in MySQL column of type `DATE`. That type is date-only, without a time-of-day. So **you introduced a time-of-day value needlessly** by using the wrong classes.

Use a JDBC driver that complies with JDBC 4.2 or later to exchange values with the database using the java.time classes.

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

And pass to a `PreparedStatement`.

```
myPstmt.setObject( … , myLocalDate ) ;
```

Comment: Detect a sense of frustration with apparently unrepentant `java.util.Date` users, I do. Unfortunately I am unable to reprogram the API I am using at this point, otherwise I most definitely would have implemented the way you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

I don't no why but this code work for me :)

**LocalDate ld =new java.util.Date(personEntity.getBirthday().getTime()).toInstant()
                            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();**

and this do not work :

**LocalDate ld =personEntity.getBirthday().getTime().toInstant()
                            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();**

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
java.util.Date input = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(input.getTime());
LocalDate date = instant .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use an SimpleDateFormat to help you?

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.Date;

public class Utils {

    private static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat( "yyyy-MM-dd" );

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        LocalDate ld = sqlDateToLocalDate( new java.sql.Date( System.currentTimeMillis() ) );
        System.out.println( ld );
    }

    public static LocalDate sqlDateToLocalDate( java.sql.Date sqlDate ) {

        try {
            Date d = sdf.parse( sdf.format( sqlDate ) );
            return d.toInstant().atZone( ZoneId.systemDefault() ).toLocalDate();
        } catch ( ParseException exc ) {
        }

        return null;

    }

}
```

Comment: I recommend you minimize the use of the outdated classes like `Date` and certainly don’t introduce the notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat`. Also this solution is somewhat more complicated than the one in the other answer.

Comment: You are using outdated classes now supplanted by the java.time classes.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Your premise of crossing over between `java.sql.Date` and `java.util.Date` is incorrect.

> If I use java.util.Date … on a variable which happens to be a java.sql.Date

You violated the contract laid out in the class documentation. You were told to ignore the fact that `java.sql.Date` is a subclass of `java.util.Date`.

But the solution may be quite simple.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = myJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ) ;
```

## Details

Apparently you have in hand a `java.sql.Date`. That class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone. At least that is the intention of that class. A tragically poor design choice was made to subclass from `java.util.Date` which, despite the name, represents a date *and* a time-of-day in UTC. This inheritance relationship is a hack, a bad hack, where they set the internal time-of-day to "00:00:00". The documentation clearly instructs us to ignore this inheritance relationship, and ignore the fact of having a time-of-day component, and pretend that the two `Date` classes are unrelated. But many people such as the author do not carefully read that documentation and makes gross assumptions based on the class names.

Both `Date` classes are part of the awful mess that is the date-time framework shipped with the earliest versions of Java. These have been supplanted by the java.time classes built into Java 8 and later.

First step when encountering a legacy date-time object: Convert to java.time using new methods added to the old classes.

Convert our fake date-only object `java.sql.Date` to a true date-only object of type `java.util.LocalDate`. The “Local” word indicates no time zone or offset-from-UTC.

```
LocalDate ld = myJavaSqlDate.toLocalDate() ;
```

Apparently you want to transform that date-only value to a date with time of day. Perhaps you want the first moment of the day. Determining the first moment requires a time zone. For example, a new day dawns earlier in `Europe/Paris` than in `America/Montreal`, and still earlier in `Asia/Kolkata`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ; 
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```